# Paypal Business Pro Account

Tags: android, paypal

Sandbox Business account accept card and payment but
Paypal Business account does not accept card , it requires Pro account for card. I want to ask whether i am right or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A live account will allow people to pay with a card without logging in.  It's called guest checkout.

It's not available for all buyer/seller pairs, though.  The countries involved and other variables can affect whether or not it's available for a given buyer during checkout.

Also, there are different versions of the PayPal checkout pages that they are split testing, so while they all offer the same features, some display it more prominently than others.